# Meteor says the MAIL_URL variable is not set, but it is

Tags: meteor, mandrill

I'm using this Mandrill package:

https://atmospherejs.com/wylio/mandrill

When I try to send an email I get this error:

```
I20150423-22:09:09.078(-7)? ====== BEGIN MAIL #0 ======
I20150423-22:09:09.078(-7)? (Mail not sent; to enable sending, set the MAIL_URL environment variable.)
I20150423-22:09:09.079(-7)? MIME-Version: 1.0
I20150423-22:09:09.079(-7)? From: admin@example.com
I20150423-22:09:09.079(-7)? To: victor@example.com
I20150423-22:09:09.079(-7)? Subject: Something something
I20150423-22:09:09.079(-7)? Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
I20150423-22:09:09.079(-7)? Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
I20150423-22:09:09.079(-7)? 
I20150423-22:09:09.079(-7)? Some kind of message content.
I20150423-22:09:09.079(-7)? ====== END MAIL #0 ======
```

So I go into the Meteor Shell and I get this:

```
> process.env.MAIL_URL
'smtp://MY_MANDRILL_EMAIL:MY_MANDRILL_API_KEY@smtp.mandrillapp.com:587/'
```

Uh, so the MAIL_URL variable IS being set....

Just to be sure, I put this in a `mailer.js` file under the `server` folder.

```
Meteor.startup(function () {
  process.env.MAIL_URL = 'smtp://MY_MANDRILL_EMAIL:MY_MANDRILL_API_KEY@smtp.mandrillapp.com:587/';
});
```

The same error happens. This is just running everything in localhost.

**EDIT - I got it working, but I don't know why I'm doing this:**

I noticed through some console logging that the email was trying to be shot off before the environmental variable was being set, despite setting the environmental variable inside of `Meteor.startup()`

What I ended up doing was creating a `mailer_variable.js` file inside `server/lib`

```
process.env.MAIL_URL = 'smtp://MY_MANDRILL_EMAIL:MY_MANDRILL_API_KEY@smtp.mandrillapp.com:587';
console.log('this is the mail_url: ', process.env.MAIL_URL);
```

This works. But I'm not sure why. It certainly isn't what the Mandrill package author says I should be doing...

Answer (score 2):

I believe this has to do with the [load order of Meteor](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/fileloadorder). I don't recommend setting environment variables in the startup script precisely for this reason.

The correct way to set this is on Linux/Mac is to start Meteor like this:

```
MAIL_URL="smtp://.../" meteor
```

or

```
export MAIL_URL="smtp://.../"
meteor
```

More details are documented here: http://meteorpedia.com/read/Environment_Variables